# Value of a global variable redeclared in the scope of a function

Tags: javascript, scope, var

My question might be a little "schoolish" but i fell upon that block of code and i realized i didn't understand why it returned "undefined". By using the Chrome debugger, i noticed the `a` variable seems to become `undefined` the moment we enter the function. My first feeling was that block of code would return 2.

If anyone can put some light on this example, that would be much appreciated

```
  var a = 2;
  console.log((function(condition){
       if (condition) {
          var a = 4;
          return a;
      } else {
          return a;
      }
  })(false))
```

In case the title of this question is not clear enough, i let you suggest something else more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

A `var` declaration is always interpreted as if it were written at the top of the function body, so your code is run as

```
  var a = 2;
  console.log((function(condition){
       var a;
       if (condition) {
          a = 4;
          return a;
      } else {
          return a;
      }
  })(false))
```

Since `condition` is false, the `else` clause runs and the function returns the uninitialized value of `a`. The local `var` declaration hides the relatively global `a` declared outside the function; it plays no part in the way the function behaves.

If you had declared the local `a` with `let` instead of `var`, things would be different. The `a` reference in the `else` clause *would* have referred to the more global `a`. A `let` declaration is scoped to it's enclosing block statement, unlike `var` which always makes function-scoped variables.

Comment: that's a great explanation ! it's clear for me now ! thank you very much

Comment: Might "var which always makes function-scoped variables" be also stated as "var which always makes closure-scoped variables"?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss well that's accurate too, but for somebody learning the language the term "function" is pretty easy to grasp because it's there on the screen in front of them, while the term "closure" is kind-of vague. I know what it means but it'd take a while to describe it.